# How can I format a SD card with the installed linux over it?

Tags: sd-card

I install a ubuntu 12.04 in a SD card. Then I want to format it. I can not format it in Linux with dd  or fdisk -l commands . How can I format it in a windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

you only can format it by mobile. insert the sd card in the mobile and go to settings->storage->format sd card

How did you install ubuntu on the sd card??

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with SD cards by booting sysrescueCD and using GParted to resize and reformat partitions.   My USB memory stick is formatted to boot sysrescueCD and because it is on my keyring, it is always at the ready.